# Как отправлять сообщения в телеграм без бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Название вопроса странное, но я не знаю, как иначе описать. Недавно начал встречать в чатах рекламные сообщения, казалось бы, ничего необычного. Там указано, что для дальнейших действий необходимо перейти в аккаунт, отправивший это сообщение. Перехожу в аккаунт и попадаю в переписку, но не с ботом, а с обычным аккаунтом. Это обычный аккаунт, никакого /start или чего-либо подобного. Я пишу "Привет" и спустя секунду мне приходит шаблонное сообщение. Это настолько меня впечатлило, что я очень хочу научиться делать так же, но я никак не смог найти ни, как это называется, ни как такое сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста. Подскажите, как это называется и, возможно, ссылку с хорошим уроком на подобное.
Вот ссылки на скрины для понимания:

аккаунт - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ9lz.png

переписка - https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5e5R.png

Comment: Возможно это юзербот

Comment: Сейчас многие CRM имеют поддержку телеграма. Полагаю вы наткнулись на одну из таких интеграций. Какие-то работают через ботов, а другие через полноценные учетки прикидываясь десктопным клиентом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Talleyran, подобное действительно можно сделать с помощью юзерботов. Ответ найден

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать прямую ссылку на диалог.
[https://web.telegram.org/k/#Номер](https://web.telegram.org/k/#%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80) диалога